# TestNG XML created programmatically not executing testcases

Tags: java, xml, testng

I created a class that is supposed to create and execute an testng xml file.

```
public static void runTestNG_XML() {
    XmlSuite suite = new XmlSuite();
    suite.setName("All_TC");
    XmlTest test = new XmlTest(suite);
    test.setName("All_TC");
    XmlRun xmlRun = new XmlRun();
    xmlRun.onInclude(test.getName());
    List<XmlPackage> packages = new ArrayList<XmlPackage>();
    packages.add(new XmlPackage("testCases.*"));
    test.setXmlPackages(packages);
    List<XmlSuite> suites = new ArrayList<XmlSuite>();
    suites.add(suite);
    TestNG tng = new TestNG();
    tng.setXmlSuites(suites);
    TestListener tla = new TestListener();
    tng.addListener((ITestNGListener) tla);
    tng.run();
}
```

This will generate the next XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="All_TC">
  <test name="All_TC">
    <packages>
      <package name="testCases.*"/>
    </packages>
  </test> <!-- All_TC -->
</suite> <!-- All_TC -->
```

At execution the testcases are not executed.
Total tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Skips: 0

If I run the XML as TestNG suite it works.

What is noticed is that when running it manualy, in console I have before execution tests:

```
[TestNG] Running: C:\Xml_Path\testng_auto.xml
```

but when running using the class above I have before execution starts:

```
[TestNG] Running: Command line suite
```

but this might be because CMD is used.

Tests:

```
package testCases;

import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class Scenario_1 {

    @Test
    public void TestCase_1() {
        System.out.print("test1");
    }

    @Test
    public void TestCase_2() {
        System.out.print("test2");
    }

}
```

testng-version: 6.14.3

Thanks,

Update <-------------

I added Verbose level and I get the following error.

[TestNG] No tests found. Nothing was run

I tried to change the XmlPackage to:

```
test.src.test.java.testCases.*
src.test.java.testCases.*
test.java.testCases.*
java.testCases.*
test.src.test.java.testCases
src.test.java.testCases
test.java.testCases
java.testCases
```

nothing worked. Here is the project structure:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in your code.

I am guessing that `Executor.createXML.java` is where the method `runTestNG_XML()` resides in.

From the screenshot, it looks like this class resides in `src/main/java` but the test class package that it is trying to add viz., `testCases` package is residing in `src/test/java`.

You cannot have java code that resides in `src/main/java` refer to java code that resides in `src/test/java`. That explains why TestNG cannot find your test classes and nothing runs.

To fix this, either move `Executor.createXML.java` to `src/test/java` (or) 
Move your package `testCases` to `src/main/java`

Comment: Worked when adding the class under src/test/java.

Comment: @NeaguV - can you please accept the answer so that the question gets closed?